# Master's theorem applicability.

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I have to find out if the following recurrence can be solved with the master theorem:

$$T(n) = 3T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n^{\log\log n}$$

I have figured that, here, I have the third case because $f(n) > n^{\log_2 3}$ but it understand that, in order for master to be applicable, $f(n)$ must be polynomially larger than $n^{\log_23}$ and I have no idea how to verify it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third case asks for (here, $a=3,b=2$)

- $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_2 3+\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$
- $3f(\frac{n}{2})\leq \kappa f(n)$ for some $\kappa < 1$ (and any $n$ large enough)

Observe than $f(n) = n^{\log \log n} = 2^{\log n\cdot \log \log n}$; $f$ is not polynomial, it's asymptotically greater than *any* polynomial (in particular, for $\epsilon=1$, $n^{\log_2 3+1} = 2^{\log n\cdot(\log_2 3+1)} = o(2^{\log n\cdot \log \log n})$. The first condition holds.

The second too, as
\begin{align*}
\frac{3f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{f(n)} &= 3\cdot 2^{\log(\frac{n}{2})\cdot \log \log( \frac{n}{2}) - \log n\cdot\log\log n} = 3\cdot 2^{\log(n)\cdot \log \log( \frac{n}{2}) - \log \log( \frac{n}{2}) - \log n\cdot\log\log n} \\
&=3\cdot 2^{\log(n)\cdot \left(\log \log( \frac{n}{2}) - \log\log n \right)- \log \log( \frac{n}{2})} = 3\cdot 2^{\log(n)\cdot \left(\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{\log n} \right) \right)- \log \log( \frac{n}{2})} \\
&= 3\cdot 2^{\log(n)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\log n}+o(\frac{1}{\log n}) \right)- \log \log( \frac{n}{2})} = 3\cdot 2^{-1- \log \log( \frac{n}{2}) + o(1)}\\
&= \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\log\frac{n}{2}}\cdot 2^{o(1)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0
\end{align*}

(you can also get a sanity check to see this limit is indeed $0$ with [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+3%28n%2F2%29%5E%28Log%5B2%2CLog%5B2%2C%28n%2F2%29%5D%5D%29%2Fx%5ELog%5B2%2CLog%5B2%2Cn%5D%5D+at+n%3Dinfinity), although it is not a proof)

Comment: I still didnt understand how did you demonstrate that the first condition holds, could you elaborate?

Comment: Look at the exponent: one of them is $C\log n$ (for the constant $C=\log_2 3 +1$, the other one is $\log n \cdot \log\log n$ (where $\log\log n \to \infty$, so clearly greater than $C$ for $n$ sufficiently large).

Comment: I see now, it was actually very obvious.